# passing dynamic value from response of one request as input of second request in Jmeter

Tags: rest, jmeter, performance-testing

I have created a HTTP request of a REST service in Jmeter and getting back a unique token id with i have to use in other request of REST service methods are POST and data payload is of type JSON

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Regular Expression Extrator.

http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is called Co-relation process. i.e. extracting something from response of previous request and passing it as input parameter to next request.

You can do it using **Regex Extractor**, **Xpath Extractor**. 
I think you have asked the another question with details. I have answered there also.